# Mergin two tables from different databases

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have two tables from two different databases.

For example:

```
Table: Articles1 - Database: db1
Attributes: id date headline text

Table: Articles2 - Database: db2
Attributes: id date headline text
```

Now i want to make an article feed with articles from both tables combined and sorted by date. From my knowledge it isnt possible to make queries across two different databases?

What can i do ? Make a temporary table and insert alle articles and sort and print? Make a cronjob getting all articles?

Btw. im doing it with MS SQL and ASP.

Thanks in advance

---

After i receieved som answers i'm trying to do this:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "Provider=Provider;Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=Catalog1;User Id=myID;Password=myPassword1;"
Set Conn2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn2.Open "Provider=Provider;Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=Catalog2;User Id=myID;Password=myPassword2;"

strSQL = "SELECT id, datetime, headline, text "&_
            "FROM Conn.dbo.vArticles "&_
            "UNION ALL "&_
            "SELECT AutoID as id, Dato as datetime, Notat as headline, Notat as text "&_
            "FROM Conn2.dbo.Notat WHERE NotatTypeID = '5'"

DIM objRS
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open mySQL, Conn


objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn = Nothing
```

But getting some errors.

Comment: You need to tell us what errors.

Comment: ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Comment: Update: Invalid object name 'Conn.dbo.vTest2'.

Comment: `FROM Conn.dbo.vArticles` doesn't seem correct. Are `Conn` and `Conn2` the names of your databases? I've updated my answer to highlight what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to query across 2 different databases. Just use 3 part name format.

```
SELECT id, date, headline, text 
FROM db1.dbo.Articles1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date, headline, text 
FROM db2.dbo.Articles2
```

The above assumes that the databases are on the same SQL Server instance. If not you will need to set up a linked server and use 4 part name format.

Comment: I'm trying to this but not quite working. Check the updates for my question.

Comment: What i dont understand is how you will do the connection with two different connections ? What is db1 and db2? Can i see the connection strings?

Comment: The connection is a connection to the host. As long as the databases reside on the same host, it will be able to query them both

Comment: I understand now.. I didnt knew that you could query them both even if they got different connection information. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but if as long as the databases reside on the same host, you may be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT db,id,date,headline,text
FROM (
    SELECT 'db1' AS db,id,date,headline,text FROM db1.dbo.Articles1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'db2' AS db,id,date,headline,text FROM db2.dbo.Articles2
) tmp
ORDER BY date DESC
```

UPDATE:

Based on the code you have supplied:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "Provider=Provider;Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=Catalog1;User Id=myID;Password=myPassword1;"

strSQL = "SELECT id, datetime, headline, text "&_
            "FROM db1.dbo.vArticles "&_
            "UNION ALL "&_
            "SELECT AutoID as id, Dato as datetime, Notat as headline, Notat as text "&_
            "FROM db2.dbo.Notat WHERE NotatTypeID = '5'"

DIM objRS
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open strSQL, Conn

objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn = Nothing
```

Where db1 and db2 are the names of your databases. I'm not used to asp so I'm not 100% sure of the syntax

There does seem to be a mistake in the variable name you call for the SQL statement. I've updated the line `objRS.Open mySQL, Conn` to `objRS.Open strSQL, Conn`